# getting Locale session on Laravel and selecting query accordingly

Tags: laravel, locale

I am trying to just select a sql query depending on the session set for the locale language. Yet, as simple as it should be, now I am getting at the View an "invalid argument for the foreach array", that is, it is not passing arguments. Before having the check locale addition, it did return correctly for English, but as I am adding now another language, the IF is not taking decisions because the check session somehow is not properly written or I dont know what. I have been googling and it read like this:

```
if (\Session::get('locale') == 'en')


    {

         $listings = \DB::table('properties')
        ->join('english_descriptions', 'property_id', '=', 'properties.id' )
        ->select('endescription','properties.id','houses1','price', 'bedrooms', 'm2', 'entitle')
        ->get();

        return $listings;

    }

    else{
    if (\Session::get('locale') == 'es')


    {


         $listings = \DB::table('properties')
        ->join('spanish_descriptions', 'property_id', '=', 'properties.id' )
        ->select('esdescription','properties.id','houses1','price', 'bedrooms', 'm2', 'estitle')
        ->get();

        return $listings;


    }
```

My controller function looks like this now:

```
public function showListings()
    {  
        var_dump(\Session::getLocale());

        $listings = Property::returnListings();

        return \View::make('listings', compact('listings'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you always have a fallback return value when using `if-statements`.

```
$listings = []; // this will be the default return value if no condition is met

if (\Session::get('locale') == 'en') {
     // query for listings in 'en'
}
else if (\Session::get('locale') == 'es') {
    // query for listings in 'es'
}

return $listings;
```

Now for the locale Session, dump the value of  `\Session::get('locale')` to check if the value is really `en` or `es`.

You might want to retrieve your locale value not from session but from the App itself using `\App::getLocale();`

Comment: where can I write this: var_dump(\Session::get('locale'));  because if I put it on the controller, it just annoys the code and the page won't load. I can see your point in what you indicated, and I am curious to see what the var_dump delivers, (although it can only be either en or es) but that should have not affected the if query even missing the default as there cannot be other session that that.

Comment: Just to be safe when in case you add another locale and forgot to add another if statement, your code will break without a default return value. dump it in your controller to see the value and you can update your question above with the dumped value.

Comment: Do `dd(\Session::get('locale'));` or `var_dump(\Session::get('locale'));exit;`

Comment: That's why not any of your if-statement is met. What laravel version are you using?

Comment: Now I changed the selected language on my dropdown menu and got this:

string(2) "es"  I am using 5.0

Comment: I will give you the right answer because at least I know now where the problem could be.

Comment: Thanks! How do you set your session locale in the backend when you select an item from the dropdown?